# Why type cast is not working here

Tags: java

Why typecast is not working in this case ?

```
int b[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    list.add(i);
    }
        Collections.sort(list);
    int c = (int) list.get(0); // This line is giving error
```

How to resolve this error??

Answer (score -10, accepted):

Try like this

```
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
    int c=list.get(0);
```

Comment: Although this has been marked as the acceped answer, it should be noted for the posterity that this is really a bad solution : it converts an integer to a string and the string back to an integer instead of using a generic ArrayList<Integer>.

Comment: Hmmm. Even if this works, its disappointing to see it as the accepted answer given the higher quality ones below...

Comment: It is not so weird if the OP actually has a bigger program, but for clearity boiled it down to this. The question was about the typecast. Although, I admit, it's not really likely if you want to ask something about a list of strings you make this your example :)

Answer (score 10):

line 2, instead of

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
```

try:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

and instead:

```
int c = (int) list.get(0);
```

just do:

```
int c = list.get(0);
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is "Cannot cast from Object to int". The compiler wants an object there, e.g.

```
int c = (Integer) list.get(0);
```

which first casts the `Object` back to the `Integer` and then auto-unboxes it to an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

The object cannot be converted to an integer type... define the type of the data that the list will contain as

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Hope this helps.